# Probability: How many ways can be ordered.

Tags: probability

A cafe serves 6 kinds of soups, 5 kinds of salads, and 20 kinds of entrees.

Q: How many ways can I order a salad or a soup?

there are 5 + 6 =  11 ways.

but I'm confused whether I need to consider for other 20 kinds of entrees.

then it should be  c(31, 11)(?) because total is 31.

Comment: Looks like there's a piece of information missing - what is an "order"? Is it a single meal, or can it include, for instance a soup and a salad, or a soup and an entree? Essentially, what are the restrictions on an "order"?

Comment: Since the question says nothing about entrees, I think you ignore the 20 entrees, and stick with the $5+6$.

Comment: @GlenO Hi. THere is no other info other than this. if it was soup and salad, then I think it should be 5*6 = 30 ways to order.

Comment: @hibc: But it's not clear. For instance, if you can order any of the soups or no soup, and any of the salads or no salad, and any of the entrees or no entree, as a combination, then there are $7\cdot6-1 = 41$ ways of choosing either a salad or a soup or both, and then $21$ ways of choosing an entree (or no entree), for a total of $41\cdot 21=861$ ways of ordering a salad or a soup with a possibility of an entree. If you can only order one dish, then the answer is simply $5+6=11$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Compilation of comments:

- If one is required to pick one item from the combined menu of soups and salads, then there are $11$ choices, since the combined menu has $6+5=11$ items.
- If one is required to pick one soup and one salad, then there are $6\cdot 5 = 30$ choices.
- If one is required to pick at most one soup and at most one salad, then there are $7\cdot 6 = 42$ choices. But really $41$, since empty orders are generally frowned upon.